# Using Selenium on iPad?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use a selenium application, and I make test on my computers browsers. It opens and manage the browsers.

Would there be a way to simulate an iPad and run this same code on it? Same thing for a cellphone?

So far I found people who wrote they did so by emulation but did not say how...

Comment: I know for sure that you can use `selenium+chromedriver` on `Android` devices. For `iOS` devices you can use `Appium` (http://appium.io/)

Comment: thanks!! I'm not sure I understand fully for android. I would need to run my application directly on an android?

Comment: No. You should connect your device with `USB`-cable and run your script as usual. But few more actions required to do this

Comment: BTW if you post your explanation as answer, I would mark it as answer so question is not left unanswered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use `selenium` code with `Android` device browser, try following:

- install [`Android SDK`](http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/) on your computer to get access to `Android Debug Bridge (adb)` features
- start `adb` server from `cmd`/`Terminal` with `"adb start-server"` command 
  (*target device should be already connected*)
- start in the same way `chromedriver` server with `"chromedriver"` command (*[`chromedriver`](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/) executable should be already in your system `Path`*)

  *you should see something like:*

  *`Starting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3) on port 9515`(in my case it always starts on `9515` port, but you have to check this value to use it in next step)*
- run code with `'androidPackage':com.android.chrome'` `chromeOptions` and instance of remote `webdriver`. `Python` code looks like:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  capabilities = {'chromeOptions': {'androidPackage':com.android.chrome',}}
  driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:9515', capabilities)  # 9515 is mentioned port number on which chromedriver server started
  driver.get('http://google.com')
  driver.quit()
  ```

P.S. It's not a direct answer on question how to use `selenium` with `iPad`, but OP asks for `selenium + Android` also

Answer (score 4):

I execute iPad testing via emulation using ChromeDriver. Does this help? With C#:

```
IWebDriver driver;
ChromeOptions ipadOptions = new ChromeOptions();
string deviceName = "Apple iPad";
ipadOptions.EnableMobileEmulation(deviceName);
driver = new ChromeDriver(ipadOptions);
```

My biggest struggle was testing requirements depending on orientation (landscape vs. portrait.) It doesn't support switching orientation which is ridiculous.

Comment: seem easy thx!! deviceName = "Apple iPad", is it a fixed parameter?

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your "fixed param" question... but the string you pass in EnableMobileEmulation can be whatever device you want to emulate. This is the list of strings I currently have for emulation using ChromeDriver:
Apple iPhone 4, Apple iPhone 5, Apple iPhone 6, Apple iPhone 6 Plus, Google Nexus 4, Google Nexus 5

Comment: thanks!! exactly what I was looking for!! by fixed I meant that only some values are recognized!!